# Understanding a Class D amplifier design

Tags: amplifier, circuit-design, audio, class-d

I've been trying to build a simple class D amplifier. I've seen through the block diagrams and design considerations online, but recently came across an amplifier design which doesn't seems to fit the majority of the circuits online.

In the input stage, we use a comparator to modulate the input audio signal to PWM, but the circuit below doesn't seem to include any triangle wave generator or comparator circuitry. [The circuit is from an Infineon tutorial. There isn't any explanation either.](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-Class_D_audio_amplifier_design_tutorial-Training-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=8ac78c8c85ecb34701866de8bb7b5297#:%7E:text=Class%20D%20amplifier%20uses%20MOSFETs,OFF%20states%20in%20output%20devices.&text=The%20output%20signal%20of%20comparator,is%20higher%20than%20the%20sawtooth.&text=Efficiency%20can%20be%20improved%20further!) The PDF file contains the circuitry. It would be helpful if someone explained how this is supposed to work in general and the idea behind these components.

[image: Reference design]

Comment: Are you referring to the block diagram on page 49 and the schematic on page 50?

Comment: yup, that one,I forgot to mention.

Comment: Look up how a sigma-delta ADC works. This is very similar.

Answer (score 12):

As Justme mentioned in the [other answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/696702/166183), there are many ways to build analog-to-digital modulators. I'll try to explain the particular scheme used in this circuit in a bit more detail.

Overall, the goal of a class-D modulator is to generate a digital signal whose time-average is equal to the input analog signal, potentially amplified by some factor.

This can be expressed as an equation like this:

```
moving_avg(Vout, t) = A * Vin(t)
```

Where Vout and Vin are the input and output signals, respectively. Vout is a digital PWM signal with a certain high and low level, while Vin is a continuous analog signal.

To make this equation represent the actual circuit more closely, we'll have to use a small trick: The analog input signal (Vin) has a much lower bandwidth than the switching frequency of Vout. In other words, the voltage Vin changes slowly compared to Vout. This means that applying the same moving average function to Vin introduces negligible error.

Doing that, we arrive at:

```
moving_avg(Vout, t) = moving_avg(A * Vin, t)
```

The moving average function is linear, so we can rearrange this further:

```
moving_avg(Vout, t)                          = moving_avg(A * Vin, t)
moving_avg(Vout, t) - moving_avg(A * Vin, t) = 0
moving_avg(Vout - A * Vin, t)                = 0
moving_avg(Vin - Vout / A, t)                = 0
```

Now we can use another fact about the moving average of a time-continuous signal: It's just the integral of that signal over the desired time window, divided by the size of the time window.

We can use that to simplify further, using tau as the integration variable because t is already taken:

```
moving_avg(Vin - Vout / A, t)                                            = 0
1/delta_t * integral[tau = (t-delta_t) ... t] (Vin(tau) - Vout(tau) / A) = 0
integral[tau = (t-delta_t) ... t] (Vin(tau) - Vout(tau) / A)             = 0
```

Now it gets a little more tricky. That last equation tells us that the integral over any time span of size `delta_t` is zero, which means that the integral from `-infinity` to any `t` is also zero as we can chop it up into intervals of that size (infinitely many of them).

Let's use that:

```
integral[tau = (t-delta_t) ... t] (Vin(tau) - Vout(tau) / A) = 0
integral[tau = -inf ... t]        (Vin(tau) - Vout(tau) / A) = 0
```

Now that pesky `delta_t` is gone and we have an equation that we can directly turn into an electronic circuit.

The equation tells us that we have to attenuate Vout (divide it by the desired gain A of the amplifier) and subtract it from the analog input voltage Vin. This gives us `Vin - Vout / A`. We then have to integrate this difference and compare it to 0.

If the integral is positive, we've not reached our target voltage yet and need to switch Vout high. Vice-versa, if the integral is negative, we've overshot and need to switch Vout low. In other words, we need to feed the integrator's output signal into a comparator and drive the output half-bridge using the signal from that comparator.

In that way, the circuit topology follows directly from its mathematical derivation.

Compute error -> integrate error -> compare to 0V -> drive MOSFETs.

This scheme is also known as [delta-sigma modulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta-sigma_modulation). In particular, it is a one-bit first-order analog-to-digital delta-sigma modulator.

(The exact circuit by Infineon is a little bit questionable because it abuses an inverter as a comparator. Ideally you'd use a comparator with some hysteresis to get a well-defined oscillation.)

Comment: Enjoyed reading this. Thanks!

Comment: This topic seems a bit more complicated to me, I'm still a novice, but thanks for detailing about this design, although I could understand this to some extent. What's this scheme called, does this have any name?. I guess I'll stick with a simple comparator modulation as of now.

Comment: @chethanRaj It's delta-sigma modulation; I've updated the answer with a link to Wikipedia.

Comment: I guess this goes into field of DSP, correct me if I'm wrong. How can I get started to designing these circuits( The feedback ones, with all the Maths around them), I was aware of a thing like sigma-delta modulation in ADC, but couldn't figure this out of the above circuit. any resources to learn from, also can you please give your views.

Comment: @chethanRaj The core signal processing functions of this class-D amplifier - the voltage feedback loop, integrator, and comparator - are analog. The circuit is therefore doing analog signal processing, not digital signal processing (DSP), even though it does contain some digital elements. You can use a modulator like this one to "bridge the gap" between analog circuitry and an actual DSP chip (it functions as an analog-to-digital converter).

Comment: This kind of circuit has two advantages versus a digital modulator or digital PWM: 1) it takes analog feedback from the actual output, which means the amp will have PSRR whereas a PWM amp is essentially a 1-bit DAC with no PSRR. 2) There is no clock, so the transitions are not time quantized.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways of converting the analog input signal to digital bit stream that drives the speaker.

These are called modulators.

Comparing it with a triangle is just the first and simplest way of doing it, and it results into PWM wave where both edges are proportial to the audio, but the pulses run at specified PWM frequency of the triangle.

Sometimes the input signal is already digital so different kind of modulators are used.

Similar sigma-delta type of modulators can be used in analog domain too, where the digital output stream is fed back into analog domain for comparing and minimizing the error.